# Como inserir valor de uma consulta em uma variável no Shell Script?

Tags: json, script, shell-script

Tenho um `JSON` em um arquivo `nomes.txt`.

o `JSON` é :

```
{"p": { "nome": ["josé","Maria", "carlos","Artur"] }}
```

Quero jogar o valor da consulta dele em uma variável.

Mostrar o resultado dá certo :

```
#!/bin/bash

ns=`cat nomes.txt`

echo $ns

for ((i=0; i<=4; i++))
do
        echo $ns | jq -r ".p | .nome[$i]"
done
```

Mas quando tento fazer algo mais elaborado não consigo.

Quero jogar o valor do `JSON` capturado na variável mas não vai .

```
#!/bin/bash

ns=`cat nomes.txt`

echo $ns

for ((i=0; i<=4; i++))
do
        aux=$ns | jq -r ".p | .nome[$i]"
        echo "O nome $i é $aux"
done
```

O valor referente a `$aux` fica nulo.

Como posso transferir o valor para a variável `aux` ?

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um teste e acredito que você resolva isso usando o comando englobado por `$()`

Assim:

```
  aux=$($ns | jq -r ".p | .nome[$i]")
```

O teste que fiz aqui foi usando o comando `$ls`, assim:

```
ls='ls'
result=$($ls -la)
echo $result
```

No meu resultado, ele guardou a listagem de diretórios na variável `result`.

De acordo com a resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472540/difference-between-and-in-bash), `$()` significa *"Execute o comando e coloque sua saída aqui"*

Fiz até uma pergunta para ajudar nessa questão:

[Para que serve $() o cifrão seguido de parêntesis no BASH?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327578/para-que-serve-o-cifr%c3%a3o-seguido-de-par%c3%aantesis-no-bash)