# Para que serve o $() [cifrão seguido de parêntesis] no BASH?

Tags: bash

Já vi alguns exemplos de código no BASH onde se usa `$()` para poder executar um comando.

Por exemplo:

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
```

O que significa esse cifrão seguido do comando encapsulado pelo parêntesis, ou seja `$(comando)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Command Substitution $()

O `$()` tem uma função muito semelhante a crase utilizada em shell: ``` (``) ```.

O `$()`, chamado de [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
permite que um comando seja executado e tenha uma saída, ou seja, ele é executado e retorna o resultado desse comando.

Esse processo é feito em um [subshell](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), que é um "processo filho" lançado pelo shell, fazendo com que seja executado um processo paralelo, executando subtarefas ou subprocessos simultaneamente.

Ele geralmente é utilizado para retornar um valor, a ser utilizado no comando principal em que é chamado, tendo o significado de:

> "primeiro faça o que está entre `$()` e depois avalie o que está no restante da linha".

**Exemplo 1:**

```
#!/bin/bash
resultado=$(uname -m)
if [ $resultado = "x86_64" ]; then
  echo "sua versão é de 64bits"
else
  echo "sua versão é de 32bits"
fi
#retorna sua versão é de 32 bits
```

**Exemplo 2:**

```
echo "Hoje é $(date)." #retorna Hoje é Qua Set 5 13:40:50 - 03 2018
```

**Exemplo 3:**

```
ls $(pwd)/Documentos/ #retorna /home/debian/Documentos/Projetos
```

Quando se quer executar um comando aninhado em `$()`, basta ir utilizando `$()` para cada comando que deseja fazer, não se preocupando com com caractere de escape, já que os os parênteses definem isso.

**Exemplo:**

```
echo $(uname -m)$(echo $(pwd)$(echo $(whoami))) #retorna i686/home/debiandebian
```

#### Command Substitution ``

A crase, que também é um command substitution, se diferencia na parte de [aninhamento de comando](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), ela sofre de ambiguidade e "se atrapalha" na execução do comando, pois cada crase pode estar sendo aberta ou sendo fechada.

**Exemplo:**

```
echo `pwd `whoami`` #retorna /home/debian/whoami
```

Para executar comandos com ela, é necessário utilizar a barra invertida `\` para escapar os comandos e serem executados juntos, o que para a legibilidade do código e execução, se torna bem mais complexo do que utilizar `$()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
echo `echo \`pwd\`\`whoami\`` #retorna /home/debian debian
```

#### $() em expressões aritméticas

Você pode encontrar ele também em uma [expressão aritmética](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), para calcular um determinado valor, mas terá que utilizar dois parênteses de abertura e dois parênteses de fechamento, em vez de um único.

Exemplo:

```
echo $((1 + 2)) # retorna 3
```

Comment: Foi uma das melhores respostas até agora. +1

Answer (score 2):

Cifrão seguido de parêntesis `$()` é uma das maneiras de se executar comandos paralelamente no BASH utilizando subshell, retornando o resultado da execução para o comando pai.

#### O que seria uma subshell?

Subshell são subprocessos criados a partir de um script principal (processo pai) para que sejam executados em paralelo, esse processamento acontece em background como sendo a subshell uma cópia quase idêntica do processo pai. No caso de processadores com múltiplos núcleos o sistema operacional fará a distribuição de tarefas das subshells entre os núcleos do processador.

Ou seja, uma subshell é um processo filho de uma shell.

Existem outras formas de se usar subshell no Bash, uma das mais comuns são os comandos precedidos por pipes `|` todo comando que vem após um pipe é executado em uma subshell.

#### Exemplo de subshell utilizando cifrão e parênteses:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

#### Exemplo  de subshell utilizando pipe:

Neste exemplo o comando grep após o pipe `|` é executado em uma subshell:

```
ls -lah | grep php
```

> Referência: http://aurelio.net/shell/canivete/#blocos

Comment: Eu adicionei um exemplo à resposta pra ficar mais didático. Se não concordar com a edição, considere reverter ela a partir do histórico.

Comment: Uma subshell seria uma meneira de executar o comando entre parenteses `$(comando)` em um outro processo paralelo. Com isso podemos criar várias tarefas executando paralelamente em background, retornando apenas o resultado final ao processo pai.

Answer (score 2):

Muito similar à crase ``.

É chamado de [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) ([posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03)) e executa o comando numa subshell. O comando entre o `$()` ou crase (``) é executado numa subshell e a saída é colocada no comando original.

```
# Setting a variable to the contents of a text file.
File_contents1=$(cat $file1) 
File_contents2=$(<$file2) # Bash permits this also.
```

Diferente das crases, o `$()` pode ser "recursivo", você pode usar um dentro do outro.

Por exemplo:

`word_count=$( wc -w $(echo * | awk '{print $8}') )`

Tradução livre [daqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147424) :)