# Como pegar tamanho de um array string no shell script?

Tags: script, bash, shell-script

Tenho uma string que passo como parâmetro, como por exemplo :

```
 "2,3,4,5"
```

Para pegar cada ítem dela eu faço :

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1; i<=4; i++))
do
        echo "$1" | cut -d "," -f $i
done
```

Mas eu gostaria de fazer com que o laço iterasse até o tamanho máximo da string (que é variável), onde cada valor separado por virgula é um item . Então como eu posso contar o número de itens para inserir no `for`?

Exemplo: Para `"2,3,4,5"` tem-se 4 itens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade você não precisa do tamanho, basta usar `tr` para trocar a vírgula por `\n` e percorra o resultado com `for`:

```
for i in $(echo "2,3,4,5" | tr "," "\n")
do
    echo $i
done
```

Isso imprime:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Na verdade, somente o comando `echo "2,3,4,5" | tr "," "\n"` já imprime os números do jeito que você precisa. O `for` só seria necessário caso você precise fazer alguma outra coisa com os números. Se só precisa imprimi-los, um por linha, nem precisa do `for`.

---

Se você também precisa da quantidade, basta contar as linhas geradas pelo `tr`, usando `wc` (com a opção `-l`, que retorna somente a quantidade de linhas):

```
n=$(echo "2,3,4,5" | tr "," "\n" | wc -l)
```

No caso, o valor de `$n` será `4`.

---

PS: A sintaxe `$( comando )` é chamada de [*Command Substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052).