# Extrair apenas o nome de um arquivo a partir do caminho completo

Tags: linux, shell-script

Quero fazer um shell script que receba um nome de arquivo com seu caminho completo, por exemplo `/home/42/arquivoEscolhido.txt`, e extraia apenas o nome do arquivo (`arquivoEscolhido.txt`), que no caso seria tudo após a última barra (`/`), levando em conta que o nome do arquivo sempre pode mudar.

Cheguei em algo parecido com isso mas não deu certo:

```
echo -n 'Informe o arquivo: '

read dir       #/home/42/teste.txt

arq=${dir#*/}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só faltou um #: `arq=${dir##*/}` vai ser `teste.txt`

`${var#padrão}`  vai remover só até a primeira ocorrência do padrão.

`${var##padrão}`  vai remover até a última ocorrência do padrão.

Comment: Muito obrigado! It works!!

Answer (score 1):

Como se trata do caminho de um arquivo, outra opção é usar o comando [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
basename /home/42/teste.txt
```

A saída é:

```
teste.txt
```

Dentro de um script, basta executar o comando com a [sintaxe de *command substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052), colocando-o entre `$( )`:

```
echo -n 'Informe o arquivo: '

read dir       #/home/42/teste.txt

# executa o comando basename, a saída é colocada na variável arq
arq=$(basename $dir)
```

Assim, se o caminho do arquivo for `/home/42/teste.txt`, a variável `arq` terá o valor `teste.txt`.

---

#### Bônus

Segundo a [documentação](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

> strip directory and suffix from filenames

Em tradução livre:

> remove o diretório e o sufixo de nomes de arquivos

Ou seja, também pode-se passar como parâmetro o sufixo a ser retirado. Com isso, também é possível remover a extensão do arquivo, por exemplo:

```
basename /home/42/teste.txt .txt
```

Saída:

```
teste
```