# Como passar resultado de comando para uma variável em bash?

Tags: bash

Tenho o seguinte comando:

```
cat frutas.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f 1
```

Este comando devolve um inteiro para o terminal. Como faço para enviar esse valor para uma variável? Tentei algo do gênero:

```
resl=cat frutas.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f 1
```

Mas deu erro:

> -bash: ./frutas.txt: Permission denied

Conteúdo do ficheiro `fruta.txt`:

```
1:cereja:223
2:maça:23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar a sintaxe de [*Command Substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), que pode ser feita de dois jeitos.

Você pode colocar o comando entre `` ` ``:

```
resl=`cat frutas.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f 1`
```

Ou você pode colocar o comando entre `$()`:

```
resl=$(cat frutas.txt | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f 1)
```

Com isso, a saída do comando será colocada na variável `resl`. Se quiser ver seu valor, faça:

```
echo $resl
```

Neste caso o resultado é o mesmo em ambos os casos, mas há situações em que pode haver diferenças entre as abordagens. Para mais detalhes sobre as diferenças, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327633/112052), em especial o [artigo *linkado*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), que explica porque `$()` é o mais recomendado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma é usar também o awk

```
resl=$(awk -F: '{print $1,$2,$3}' frutas.txt) #-F: determina que o separador seja ':'
```

E para pegar linhas específicas:

```
resl=$(awk -F: '{if(NR==1)print $1,$2,$3}' frutas.txt) #NR é referente ao número da linha
```