# Como criar um script para renomear arquivos no Ubuntu 18?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Eu tenho uma pasta chamada `baixar-nanatsu` e dentro da pasta tenho vários vídeos. Eu queria alterar o nome dos vídeos via bash ou shell script de forma automática, só que eu não faço a mínima ideia de como faz.

Conteúdo da pasta `baixar-nanatsu`:

```
nanatsu-ep-1.mp4
nanatsu-ep-2.mp4
nanatsu-ep-3.mp4
nanatsu-ep-4.mp4
```

Gostaria de alterar de modo q fique:

1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta fazer um [`for`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/for) nos arquivos e usar o comando [`mv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) para mudar o nome dos mesmos:

```
for i in nanatsu*.mp4; do mv $i ${i#nanatsu-ep-}; done
```

O `for` percorre todos os arquivos cujos nomes correspondem a `nanatsu*.mp4` (ou seja, que começam com "nanatsu" e terminam com ".mp4"). A cada iteração a variável `i` terá o nome de um dos arquivos.

Em seguida o comando `mv` recebe o nome atual do arquivo e o novo nome que ele terá. O nome atual é `$i`, ou seja, o nome atual do arquivo.

O novo nome é `${i#nanatsu-ep-}`, que usa a sintaxe de *bash substitution* (veja o item 4 [deste tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) para mais detalhes). Basicamente ele pega o valor de `i` e remove o trecho `nanatsu-ep-`, sobrando apenas a parte final (o número seguido do ".mp4").

No final, os arquivos são renomeados da maneira que você precisa (`nanatsu-ep-1.mp4` vira `1.mp4`, `nanatsu-ep-2.mp4` vira `2.mp4`, etc).

---

Lembrando que você deve estar dentro da pasta, pois o `for` acima pega os arquivos da pasta atual. Então ficaria:

```
cd baixar-nanatsu
for i in nanatsu*.mp4; do mv $i ${i#nanatsu-ep-}; done
```

Mas se quiser rodar de qualquer lugar, você pode passar o caminho completo dos arquivos: `baixar-nanatsu/nanatsu*.mp4`. Porém o comando fica um pouco mais complicado, já que o *bash substitution* só remove os trechos do início ou final da variável:

```
for i in baixar-nanatsu/nanatsu*.mp4
do
    file=$(basename $i)
    dir=$(dirname $i)
    mv $i ${dir}/${file#nanatsu-ep-}
done
```

Como agora o `i` terá o valor `baixar-nanatsu/nome-do-arquivo.mp4`, eu uso [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) para pegar somente o nome do arquivo (sem a pasta) e [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) para pegar o nome do diretório. Para pegar a saída desses comandos eu uso a sintaxe de [*command substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052) (coloco o comando entre `$(...)`).

Em seguida eu uso esses valores para compor o novo nome do arquivo (a pasta é a mesma, e o nome usa o *bash substitution*, da mesma forma que antes.

---

Para o caso de nomes mais complexos, [como informado no seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379734/como-criar-um-script-para-renomear-arquivos-no-ubuntu-18#comment751995_379737), basta usar a substituição com `%` para remover trechos do final, juntamente com `#` para remover trechos do começo:

```
# se o nome for The.Seven.Deadly.Sins.S01E02.720p.WEB-DL.DUBLADO.WWW.COMANDOTORRENTS.COM.mkv
for i in *
do
    tmp=${i#The.Seven.Deadly.Sins.S01E}
    mv $i ${tmp%720p.WEB-DL.DUBLADO.WWW.COMANDOTORRENTS.COM.mkv}mkv
done
```

Primeiro eu removo o trecho `#The.Seven.Deadly.Sins.S01E`, e em seguida removo o restante, deixando somente o número 02 (e adiciono a extensão no final novamente).

Comment: Eu li aqui esse tutorial, mas não consegui fazer de fato o que eu queria... Os vídeos que eu tenho é <code>The.Seven.Deadly.Sins.S01E02.720p.WEB-DL.DUBLADO.WWW.COMANDOTORRENTS.COM.mkv</code>, consegui deixar <code>03.720p.WEB-DL.DUBLADO.WWW.COMANDOTORRENTS.COM.mkv</code> mas não consegui tirar o que vem após o <code>03</code>...

Comment: Realmente ajudou demais. Vou estudar um pouco mais sobre isso aí pra melhorar meus renames. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente em Linux existe (ou pode ser instalado) um comando
rename, ou prename que ajuda nessas tarefas:

```
prename 's/nanatsu-ep-//' nanatsu-ep-*.mp4
```

Ou seja:

- para todos os `nanatsu-ep-*.mp4`
- `s/nanatsu-ep-//`  substitui `nanatsu-ep-` por nada. (Pode ser uma qualquer instrução Perl que altere o nome)

De modo análogo, usando o `rename`:

```
rename nanatsu-ep- "" nanatsu-ep-*.mp4
```