# Como atribuir a uma variável o comando sed com formatação? ShellScript

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, awk

Estou tendo um problema fazendo um programa para trocar o primeiro numero por X, pois, mesmo funcionando, a variável não recebe o valor permanentemente:

```
VAR="oi                                 200          20   10"
VAR= echo "$VAR" | sed -r -n "s/[0-9]+/X/p"
echo $VAR
```

Esta saindo:

```
oi                                 X          20   10
oi 200 20 10
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para a variável receber permanentemente a troca do primeiro numero por X, e como faço para ficar com a mesma formatação, pois o sed ignora os espaços que dei e coloca apenas um no lugar.
Eu desejo que a saída seja:

```
oi                                 X          20   10
oi                                 X          20   10
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra você atribuir o resultado de um comando pra uma variável tem duas opções:

- a primeira é usar os backticks, ou seja, o acento grave (`).

```
VAR=`echo "$VAR" | sed r -n "s/[0-9]+/X/p"`
```

- a segunda seria colocar usar a sintaxe `$(comando)`

```
VAR=$(echo "$VAR" | sed r -n "s/[0-9]+/X/p")
```

O segundo caso é mais fácil de ler e permite você ir aninhando comandos mais facilmente, mas aí fica a seu critério. Caso você queira mais informações, o nome disso é [substituição de comandos](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Pra você manter a formatação com os espaços entre os números e o texto, é necessário deixar sua variável entre `"`. Portanto, o código correto seria

```
VAR="oi                                 200          20   10"
VAR=$(echo "$VAR" | sed -r -n "s/[0-9]+/X/p")
echo "$VAR"
```

Comment: Obrigada! Isso funcionou em questao de atribuir a variavel, porem a formatação fica oi X 20 10, sendo que deveria ficar com todos os espaços que eu coloquei inicialmente. Sabe como posso resolver?

Comment: atualizei a resposta pra ficar mais completo (: mas basicamente você precisa deixar sua variável entre aspas duplas pra preservar a formatação

Comment: Deu certo em relação à formatação! Mas mesmo imprimindo todos os espaços, agora fica sem o X no lugar do 200. Sabe como resolver?

Comment: eu acabei de rodar o código que coloquei ali na resposta e o X tá no lugar certo. como está seu código? está com o `$()` e com o `$VAR` entre aspas?

Comment: Consegui! Muuuuito obrigada pela gentileza e paciência!!!!!