# Como criar uma sequência de arquivos cujos nomes vêm de uma sequência numérica com intervalos pré-determinados?

Tags: shell-script

Preciso criar uma sequência de arquivos. Ex :`1.log`, `2.log`, `3.log`, `4.log` e assim sucessivamente.

Preciso definir o valor inicial e o valor final, aí ele cria para mim dentro da pasta desejada. Segue abaixo o código mais ou menos com a ideia que quero:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e " DIGITE O NUMERO INICIAL: "
read num1

echo -e " DIGITE AGORA O NUMERO FINAL: ";
read num2

#num3 = num1
#num4 = num2
cd /var/actus/digital/nfce/inutilizar/
touch {$num1..$num2}.log
ls /var/actus/digital/nfce/inutilizar/
```

Está gerando apenas um arquivo. Por exemplo, se tivesse definido `num1` igual a 1 e `num2` igual a 2, está gerando `{1..2}.log`, sendo que preciso que gerar `1.log` e `2.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar [`seq`](https://ss64.com/bash/seq.html):

```
for i in $(seq $num1 $num2)
do
    touch $i.log
done
```

`seq $num1 $num2` gera uma sequência numérica que vai de `$num1` até `$num2`. Depois fazemos um `for` para iterar nesta sequência, criando os arquivos.

Repare que o comando `seq` está entre `$( )`, pois esta é a sintaxe de [*command substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052), assim o `for` será feito no resultado do `seq` (que no caso, são os números).

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo aqui