# Shell - Introduzir ouput de programa na variável

Tags: variáveis, shell-script, shell, input-output

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
for (( c=1; c<=10; c++ ))
do
  cc stringalea.c -o st
  aux = ./st $c
  echo $aux
  ...
done
```

O programa stringalea.c devolve uma palavra pseudo-aleatória de comprimento "c".
Como eu faço para introduzir na variável aux, o output do executável "./st $c"?

Comment: Use o *command substitution*: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052

Comment: aux=$(echo ./st $c ) escreve em aux "./ st 1"

Comment: Não, é só `aux=$(./st $c)`

Comment: Outra coisa, precisa compilar o programa stringalea.c toda hora? Não é melhor compilar uma vez só antes do `for`?

Comment: ja vou alterar obrigado