# Problema com variáveis que recebem conteúdo de um comando shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Tenho um problema em um shell script que estou usando de teste para uma futura tarefa. O script é simples... tenho um arquivo texto que possui 2 colunas com o delimitador ";". Na primeria coluna há sites na internet e na segunda um número de 1 e 3.

O arquivo texto com o nome dos sites se chama **dados_entrada** e possui o conteúdo abaixo

```
www.uol.com.br;1
www.bol.com.br;2
www.google.com;3
www.globo.com;2
```

Um segundo script que fará a leitura desse arquivo é o que estou tendo problemas. Tento armazenar o conteúdo em uma variável porém algum erro está ocorrendo pois a variável fica em branco. De forma simplificada, estou testando direto diretamente no shell.

```
file_name=dados_entrada

endereco= head -n 1 $file_name | cut -d ";" -f1 |  tail -n 1
num_ping= head -n 1 $file_name | cut -d ";" -f2 |  tail -n 1
```

Ao executar os 2 comandos acima, ele escreve na tela os valores correspondentes que deveriam estar na variável porém ao entrar com o comando `echo $endereco` e `echo $num_ping` , o conteúdo é vazio conforme trecho abaixo:

```
caio@caio-debian:~/Documentos$ echo $endereco

caio@caio-debian:~/Documentos$ echo $num_ping

caio@caio-debian:~/Documentos$
```

Atualmente uso o Debian como SO.

```
caio@caio-debian:~/Documentos$ uname -a
Linux caio-debian 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que estou errando?

Agradeço pela força!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Para que serve o $() \[cifrão seguido de parêntesis\] no BASH?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327578/para-que-serve-o-cifr%c3%a3o-seguido-de-par%c3%aantesis-no-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicionei a utilização do operador `$()` para atribuir corretamente a saída do comando para a variável.

Para verificar o valor da variável o comando `echo` deve ser executado no próprio script, onde o valor atribuído a variável ainda está disponível.

```
file_name=dados_entrada

endereco=$(head -n 1 $file_name | cut -d ";" -f1 | tail -n 1)
num_ping=$(head -n 1 $file_name | cut -d ";" -f2 | tail -n 1)

echo $endereco 
echo $num_ping
```

Saída no terminal:

```
www.uol.com.br
1
```

Comment: Cara, é isso mesmo! Juro que não faltei a aula de declaração de variável! Obrigado mesmo pela força! Deu certíssimo!!