# Qual a diferenca entre SEQ e FOR I IN no shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Comecei a estudar recentemente shell script e me daparei com 2 exemplos, e gostaria de saber a diferenca dos comandos, quando é melhor usar um ou o outro. O exemplo era `seq 1 5|` e o outro era `for i in 1 2 3 4 5`, ambos vão fazer um loop de 1 até 5, são a mesma coisa?

Comment: Alan, a resposta abaixo resolveu sua dúvida ou faltou algo? Se ela resolveu o problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.
Se não resolveu, diga o que faltou que se for o caso eu edito acrescentando mais informações (desde que não desvie do assunto principal, que é a diferença entre os 2 comandos)

Answer (score 2):

No seu exemplo específico, ambos são similares. Mas eles não são exatamente a mesma coisa.

`seq` serve para gerar uma sequência de números, e nada mais. Ex:

```
# apenas o valor final (inicial é 1)
seq 5
1
2
3
4
5

# valor inicial e final
seq 3 5
3
4
5

# valor inicial, passo e valor final (números de 2 a 10, pulando de 3 em 3)
seq 2 3 10
2
5
8
```

A saída do comando são os números, um em cada linha.

---

Já o `for` itera pelos parâmetros que você informar (que podem ser os números, mas veremos mais abaixo que não se limita a isso), e você pode fazer qualquer coisa com eles (não só imprimir). Ex:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  cp arquivo$i.txt pasta
done
```

Ou seja, o `for` acima está copiando os arquivos `arquivo1.txt`, `arquivo2.txt`, etc (até o `arquivo5.txt`) para uma pasta.

O `for` pode inclusive ser usado juntamente com `seq`, caso você queira iterar pelos números:

```
# iterar de 1 a 5
for i in $(seq 1 5)
do
  # faz algo com $i
done
```

A sintaxe `$( )` é o [*command substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052), que basicamente pega a saída do comando que está entre os parênteses e os passa como parâmetros para o `for`.

Se bem que você também pode usar `for i in {1..5}` para iterar de 1 a 5.

---

Mas como eu já disse anteriormente, o `for` não se limita a números.

Por exemplo, se eu fizer `for i in *.c`, ele vai iterar por todos os nomes de arquivos que terminam com `.c` no diretório atual.

E eu posso usar o *command substitution* para colocar qualquer comando, e o `for` irá iterar pela saída do mesmo:

```
for i in $(um comando qualquer)
do
  # faz algo com $i
done
```

No caso, a saída do comando é passada para o `for`, que itera por eles. O detalhe é que por padrão ele usa como separador um caractere que seja espaço, TAB ou quebra de linha.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que a saída do comando são as 3 linhas abaixo:

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
bla bla bla
```

Se eu fizer um `for i in $(comando)`, a saída acima é passada para o `for` e a cada iteração, cada palavra é setada para a variável `i`.
Ou seja, `for i in $(comando); do echo $i; done` irá imprimir:

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
bla
bla
bla
```

Mas se você quiser que cada linha seja considerada um único parâmetro, [basta mudar o valor  da variável `IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184863):

```
# usa apenas a quebra de linha como separador
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(comando) # a cada iteração, $i será uma das linhas
do
  echo $i
done
```

Agora a cada iteração, `i` será uma das linhas, e a saída é:

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
bla bla bla
```