# rodar um laço "for" com 5 variáveis juntas

Tags: python, lista, for, shell-script, áudio

Uso um programa pra criar arquivos de áudio chamado `stem` que junta vocal, bateria, melodia, baixo e um áudio guia num único arquivo.

Estou tentando criar um laço que armazene esses arquivos e para que a aplicação possa usa lo.

Dentro da pasta eu tenho os arquivos:

```
a.vocal.m4a a.bateria.m4a a.melodia.m4a a.baixo.m4a a.master.m4a 
b.vocal.m4a b.bateria.m4a b.melodia.m4a b.baixo.m4a b.master.m4a 
c.vocal.m4a c.bateria.m4a c.melodia.m4a c.baixo.m4a c.master.m4a
```

Eu tentei rodar:

```
for f in *.vocal.m4a; for g in *.bateria.m4a; for h in *.melodia.m4a; for i in *.baixo.m4a; for j in *.master.m4a; 
do mesclar "$f" "$g" "$h" "$i" "$j" ; 
done
```

Mas o laço só funciona no último `for`. Eu gostaria de um laço que rodasse todos os arquivos "a" depois os arquivos "b" e depois os "c" e assim por diante.

Comment: Sugiro remover a tag python pois trata-se de shel script.

Answer (score 2):

Em shell script, basta fazer um *loop* pelas letras de `a` até a letra que você quer (vamos supor que seja `c`):

```bsh
for i in {a..c}
do
    mesclar $i.*
done
```

Isso, supondo que no diretório só tem os arquivos que você quer (se tiver algum outro cujo nome seja `a.algumacoisa`, ele também será passado para o comando `mesclar`). Além disso, ao usar `$i.*`, os arquivos serão passados em ordem alfabética. Se quiser restringir os arquivos e controlar a ordem, você pode mudar para:

```bsh
for i in {a..c}
do
    mesclar $(echo $i.{vocal,bateria,melodia,master}.m4a)
done
```

No caso, o `echo` imprime a letra, o ponto, e depois `vocal`, `bateria`, etc, nesta ordem. Ou seja, os arquivos são passados na ordem desejada. E eu uso a sintaxe de [*command substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052) para que a saída do `echo` seja passada para o comando `mesclar`.

Se em vez de `a`, `b`, `c`, etc, os nomes podem ser qualquer coisa (não necessariamente uma sequência), você pode colocá-los separados por vírgula.

Além disso, uma vez tendo esses nomes, você pode compor o comando da maneira que quiser. Usando o exemplo do [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/464398/rodar-um-la%c3%a7o-for-com-5-vari%c3%a1veis-juntas/464498#comment879510_464498), ficaria:

```bsh
for i in {nome,outronome,maisoutro}
do
    mesclar $(echo $i.{melodia,vocal,baixo,bateria}.m4a) -x $i.master.m4a
done
```

Que chamará os comandos:

```
mesclar nome.melodia.m4a nome.vocal.m4a nome.baixo.m4a nome.bateria.m4a -x nome.master.m4a
mesclar outronome.melodia.m4a outronome.vocal.m4a outronome.baixo.m4a outronome.bateria.m4a -x outronome.master.m4a
mesclar maisoutro.melodia.m4a maisoutro.vocal.m4a maisoutro.baixo.m4a maisoutro.bateria.m4a -x maisoutro.master.m4a
```

---

Em Python a ideia é parecida, bastando usar [uma das muitas formas de se chamar processos externos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228) para chamar o comando. Exemplo com [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.system):

```py
import os

files = ['vocal', 'bateria', 'melodia', 'master']
for i in 'abc':
    params = ' '.join(f'{i}.{file}.m4a' for file in files)
    os.system(f'mesclar {params}')
```

Ou, com uma lista de nomes e o comando indicado nos comentários:

```py
import os

files = ['melodia', 'vocal', 'baixo', 'bateria']
for i in ['nome', 'outronome', 'maisoutro']:
    params = ' '.join(f'{i}.{file}.m4a' for file in files)
    os.system(f'mesclar {params} -x {i}.master.m4a')
```

Que chamará os comandos:

```
mesclar nome.melodia.m4a nome.vocal.m4a nome.baixo.m4a nome.bateria.m4a -x nome.master.m4a
mesclar outronome.melodia.m4a outronome.vocal.m4a outronome.baixo.m4a outronome.bateria.m4a -x outronome.master.m4a
mesclar maisoutro.melodia.m4a maisoutro.vocal.m4a maisoutro.baixo.m4a maisoutro.bateria.m4a -x maisoutro.master.m4a
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. pode ser que eu nao tenha me expressado direito. o comando que eu uso e assim :

python ./ni-stem.py create -m ./StemMetadata.json -s "./arquivo.melodia.m4a" "./arquivo.vocal.m4a" "./arquivo.baixo.m4a" "./arquivo.bateria.m4a" -x "./arquivo.master.m4a" 

estou tentando uma maneira e otimizar o processo relazando um comando para todos os arquivos da pasta . no caso fazer um laco para ler o endereco dos arquivos tipo "a". depois para o tipo "b". a e b sao exemplos, vou ter outros nomes. mas todos eles vao ter melodia, vocal, baixo, bateria e master

Comment: @underson14 Atualizei a resposta com mais uns exemplos, veja se é o que precisa

Answer (score 0):

Use a função zip(). Com ela vc pode percorrer várias listas.

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for l, n in zip(letters, numbers):
...     print(f'Letter: {l}')
...     print(f'Number: {n}')

Letter: a
Number: 0
Letter: b
Number: 1
Letter: c
Number: 2
Letter: d
Number: 3
Letter: e
Number: 4
```

Comment: o conceito teórico é bom - mas s eprestar atençã ona pergunta, não é isso que está sendo pedido - e sim, rodar o comando "mesclar <arquivos>" primeiro com os arquivos que começam com "a" - e assim por diante.

Comment: @brunoi-campos eu tentei fazer algo assim :

cd ./audio

criei uma arquivo ./teste02.gyp com:

for a, b, c, d, e in zip(*.1.melodia.m4a, *.2.vocais.m4a, *.3.baixo.m4a, *.4.bateria.m4a,*.5.master.m4a):
    python './ni-stem.py' create -m './StemMetadata.json' -s f'{a}' f'{b}' f'{c}' f'{d}' -x f'{e}'

fiz python ./teste02.gyp

e apareceu:

File "./teste02.gyp", line 2
    python './ni-stem.py' create -m './StemMetadata.json' -s f'{a}' f'{b}' f'{c}' f'{d}' -x f'{e}'
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

oque aconteceu?