# Como copiar arquivos de um diretório para outro usando regex?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

No terminal do linux, quando quero listar arquivos em um diretório usando regex, eu faço:

```
#exemplo listando arquivos começando com uma letra maiúscula
ls | grep -oP '^[A-Z].+'
```

A flag `oP` é usada para que o output mostre apenas os matches (`o`) e para que eu possa aplicar a regex do Perl (`P`).

Eu gostaria de poder também utilizar esse recurso para copiar arquivos entre diretórios. Para copiar arquivos sem regex faço, por exemplo:

```
cp /Documents/file.txt .
```

Usando regex, eu tentei:

```
cp ~/Downloads/ | grep -oP '(AB|HU).+' .
```

que retorna o erro:

```
grep: .cp: missing destination file operand after '/home/lucas/Downloads/'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
: Is a directory
```

Da forma como entendo, o destino seria `.`, ou seja, o diretório atual, mas não funcionou.

Como posso lidar com esse erro?

Comment: Dica: você pode usar o comando `find` com o parâmetro `-regex` usando uma função `-exec`. Exemplo: [Find command with -regex and -exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390639/find-command-with-regex-and-exec-regex-help-needed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao usar `|` ([também conhecido como "pipe"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33434465)), cada uma das partes (tanto antes quanto depois do `|`) devem ser um comando completo. Basicamente, a saída do primeiro comando se torna a entrada do segundo, por isso que `ls | grep ...` funciona (a saída do comando `ls` se torna a entrada do `grep`, ou seja, o `grep` usa os nomes dos arquivos para fazer a busca de acordo com os critérios informados).

Então ao fazer `cp ~/Downloads/ | grep -oP '(AB|HU).+' .` na verdade ele tenta executar primeiro `cp ~/Downloads` e depois a saída dele seria enviada para `grep`.
E o erro ocorre porque `cp ~/Downloads/` não é um comando completo (ele entende que você está dizendo que quer copiar o diretório Downloads, mas não diz para onde). E mesmo se fosse um comando válido, a saída dele seria enviada para `grep`, o que não faria muito sentido (pois na verdade você quer que o resultado do `grep` seja passado para `cp`).

---

Se você quer copiar os arquivos que começam com letra maiúscula, nem precisaria de regex:

```bash
cp ~/Downloads/[[:upper:]]* .
```

---

Mas se a ideia é usar regex (com algum critério mais complexo do que "começa com letra maiúscula"), uma opção é usar `find`, e para que a saída deste seja passada para `cp`, use [*command substitution*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327578/112052): basta colocar o comando entre `$( )`. Assim:

```bash
cp $(find ~/Downloads -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(AB|HU).+") .
```

Ou seja, o `find` encontra os arquivos, e como ele está entre `$( )`, o resultado dele (que são os nomes do arquivos) são passados corretamente para `cp`.

Eu não usei o comando original (`ls | grep`) porque a saída só retorna os nomes do arquivos sem o nome da pasta, então você precisaria colocar novamente o nome na frente. Algo assim:

```bash
cp $(ls ~/Downloads/ | grep -oP '^(AB|HU).+' | perl -p -e 's/^/$ENV{HOME}\/Downloads\//') .
```

O que na minha opinião fica bem mais confuso do que a opção com `find`.

---

Se bem que para este caso específico, a regex é `^(AB|HU).+` (começa com "AB" ou "HU"), então também daria para substituí-la por [*brace expansion*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6035):

```bash
cp ~/Downloads/{AB,HU}* .
```

Assim, ele copia os arquivos da pasta Downloads, cujos nomes começam com "AB" ou "HU".

Com *brace expansion* também é possível pegar todos os arquivos que começam com letra maiúscula:

```bash
cp ~/Downloads/{A..Z}* .
```

O detalhe chato é que nesse caso ele vai tentar pegar todas as opções possíveis (começa com "A", com "B", etc), e caso alguma delas não exista, aparecerá uma mensagem de erro. Se quiser omitir estas mensagens, faça:

```bash
cp ~/Downloads/{A..Z}* . 2>/dev/null
```

Só que isso também vai omitir quaisquer outras mensagens de erro, então para arquivos que começam com letra maiúscula, acho melhor usar a primeira opção acima (`[[:upper:]]`).

Answer (score 2):

Já agora mais um par de variantes (na continução de @hksotsubo):

```
cp ~/Downloads/AB*  ~/Downloads/HU*  dir/
```

(ou seja expandir a alternativa nalguns casos é uma alternativa)

Embora de modo limitado podemos usar o operador reg.Exp `[...]`

```
cp ~/Downloads/[A-Z]*     dir/     ## copia os ficheiros começados por maiuscula
cp ~/Downloads/[AH][BU]*  dir/     ## copia AB* HU* mas tambem AU* e HB*
```